# Section id not working on parallax scrolling website

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have a parallax scrolling website which has arrows on to indicate to the user that they need to scroll down to view the content.

I want the user to be able to click on the arrows which will then scroll to the relevant section. From my understanding all I need to do is add an ID to the section then reference that in the href tag of the arrow. I have the following, which for some reason isn't working and just adds the ID to the end of the URL but doesn't scroll down:

HTML:

```
<!-- Button -->
<a class="green-arrow" href="#backupsection">
   <img  src="img/green-arrow.svg">
</a>

<!-- Backup 2 -->
<section id="backupsection" class="background">
  <div class="content-wrapper-left">
    <p class="backup-text-title">Methods</p>
    <p class="backup-text">No surprises here then: tape as a primary backup method remains at an all-time low of 3%. This is the first year it hasn’t fallen – possibly indicative of how stubborn some legacy systems (often populated with static compliance data) can be.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You give a class to the buttons you will click and then give them the id "hook"

```
        <a class="button"  href="#about">About</a>
        <a  class="button" href="#service">Services</a>
        <a  class="button" href="faqs.html">Galleries</a>
        <a  class="button" href="#contact">Contact</a>
```

And the rest is done with jQuery, to make it a smooth animation, instead of just jumping to the page section. Here is the pen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/wKKbjO

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple demo maybe you can do more above it.

```
$(".green-arrow").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#backupsection").offset().top
    }, 2000);
})
```

at the same time i made a div element whose height is 1000px between these two elements on purpose,this can make the effect more obviously.

Comment: Thanks for this however I had previously tried this and couldn't get it to work. For some reason the section ID's just aren't being picked up on scroll

Comment: I'm a little puzzled what you actually want to do in this process.maybe you can put an ID attribute to the section element while click on the a label.